# How can I statically link a C++ library to a C application in OSX?

Tags: c++, c, macos, static-linking, leveldb

I've looked through the other similar questions about this topic, and I think there's something OSX-specific I'm missing.

I'm trying to statically link Basho's fork of LevelDB to my C application (since packaged versions of LevelDB will use Google's mainline). Even using the c++ linker and adding -lc++ to the command line, I still get flooded with errors about missing c++ STL symbols such as:

> "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator const&)",
>   referenced from:
>         _leveldb_open in libleveldb.a(c.o)

The strange thing is, I know I have the C++ bits enabled right because I'm also linking to libsnappy, and before I added the link directive there was unresolved libsnappy symbols (obviously) that are now cleared up.

As far as I know, I have the latest version of xcode & the rest of the compiler chain. libleveldb is also compiled using the same toolchain as my regular application. Here's the command line I'm trying:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
>   -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/get_rid_status.dir/get_rid_status.c.o 
>   -o get_rid_status 
>   /usr/local/lib/libdb.a /usr/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
>   /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.dylib /usr/lib/libapr-1.dylib -lpthread -ldl -lm
>   -lz leveldb/libleveldb.a /usr/local/lib/libsnappy.dylib -lc++

I'm linking with the c++ linker and adding the c++ standard library with -lc++ to no avail.

**UPDATE**
Found the correct answer, which can be found below. Kudos to the users who told me the right etiquette when I originally answered my own question here.

Comment: You should answer the question yourself, and accept it.

Comment: You can leave this post, but remove your solution edit and submit it as an *answer* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, leveldb adds some extra linker flags I didn't notice at first. The culprit is `-mmacosx-version-min=10.8`. Adding that flag to the link step of my C application got everything to line up.

Comment: Can you post your full link command line? I added that and still get the link errors.